# Adding CPR (C++ Requests Libarary) to includePath doesn't get rid of includePath error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

So I'm using VSCode and am trying to use the whoshuu/cpr headers but it's not working.

I've tried adding cpr/include to the includePath but that hasn't done anything.

Here's my c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/cpr/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\\\mingw-w64\\\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\\\mingw32\\\\bin\\\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Expected: it letting me include cpr

Actual: includePath error.

Comment: I'm affraid this is not a c++ problem...

Comment: Especially when no C++ code is included in the question. The error could be in the code, not in the project settings. Please add the `#include` directive.